# How to reduce overhead and run applescripts faster?

Tags: applescript

I'm developing an app that may have to run many applescripts in sequence, and I am looking for any way to run applescripts faster. I'm not talking about the internals, I'm talking just about the execution startup/cleanup.

Example:

onePlusOne.applescript:

```
1+1
```

I then compiled this with `osacompile -o onePlusOne.scpt onePlusOne.applescript`

Now, the test (in a bash shell):

`time zsh -c "(( val = 1 + 1 ))"`:

```
real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.007s
```

`time osascript onePlusOne.scpt`:

```
real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.026s
sys 0m0.022s
```

I'm wondering if anything can be done about the additional overhead and to execute applescripts faster.

Comment: Applescript isn't really meant for speed, it's meant for automation. I cannot really tell you if the following statement is true, it's more of a guess, but I don't think Applescript can compile to a native executable and has to compile to some sort of bytecode since it has to interact with other programs, which not many programming languages have to do. As I said before, that is just a guess though, which I cannot confirm since Applescript isn't open-source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t say what type of app, or what kind of AppleScripts, or whether the scripts are part of the app or user-supplied. Nor do you say if you’ve actually built a prototype and identified actual performance problems, or are talking [purely hypotheticals](https://i0.wp.com/www.clarkdever.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/C1NuQ8NWIAAAEAA.jpg) at this point.

Assuming a typical sandboxed Swift/ObjC desktop app:

- For arbitrary user-supplied AppleScripts, you usually want to use `NSUserAppleScriptTask` as that runs scripts outside the app’s own sandbox. One big limitation: its subprocesses aren’t persistent, so you can’t load a script once and call its handlers multiple times; you have to create a new subprocess each time, and if you want to preserve scripts’ state between calls then you’ll have to arrange something yourself.
- Exception to the above: if your user-supplied scripts can run inside the limitations of your app’s sandbox then running them via `NSAppleScript`/`OSAScript` is an option, and those do allow you to load a script once and call it multiple times.
- For built-in AppleScripts, use the AppleScript-ObjC bridge to expose your scripts as ObjC subclasses, and [call their handlers directly](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC). The overheads there are mostly in the time it takes to cross the bridge.

Otherwise, the overheads are the overheads; there’s usually not a lot you can do about them. TBH, your average AppleScript will spend more time waiting on IO (Apple event IPC is powerful but slow) or churning through pathological algorithms (e.g. iterating a list is generally `O(n²)` due to AS’s shonky internals, and most AppleScripters are amateurs so will write inefficient code). There may be ways to ameliorate poor runtime performance, but that is a far larger discussion.

One last consideration: with AppleScript-based automation, “Is it fast?” is less important than “Is it fast than doing the same task by hand”? And even a slow AppleScript will do a job 10–100x quicker than a fast human.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of context. I wanted to keep the question straightforward. But my particular situation is that I do some automation tasks from a desktop java task. I basically have a global keyboard shortcut registered in java, and that shortcut creates a subprocess which calls `osascript -e ...` in the shell. There is a lot of overhead so the keyboard shortcut feels laggy. I have tested it and the lag is on the applescript end, not the java end. As opposed to a tool like Keyboard Maestro, where I can do this automation much faster for some reason. I am not a native OSX dev, just java.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thought-provoking and thorough response.

Comment: Sounds like you’re starting two subprocesses, spinning up 2 interpreters in the process, each time you need to eval some AS code. Yeah, that would be laggy. KM, I’m guessing, loads the AppleScripts into memory and keeps them there. Your app being Java complicates implementation. You might be best to put the AppleScript stuff into an ObjC-based helper app, using NSAppleScript to compile the script when it starts up, and then keep that process alive for the duration, using sockets or other language-independent IPC mechanism to communicate between the two.

Comment: No, to be clear it is a single daemon java launcher process which spawns applescript tasks. I use a library called jnativehook to listen for global shortcuts. Sorry I didn't describe it well above. I like your idea for creating a native interface and its good to know exactly what I'd need to do. If I ever have time to learn native apple developing which is far outside my niche, that is.

Comment: There used to be a ScriptEngine for AppleScript, which might’ve run AppleScripts in-process, but IIRC that got dropped years ago. You could have a rummage around on the offchance it’s still out there. The challenge with hosting AppleScripts in-process in Java is that without a Java-ObjC bridge to call `NSAppleScript`/`OSAKit`, your only option is the ancient OpenScripting C API, which is arcane, archaic, low-level, and based on the long-deprecated ComponentManager API. A pain to use in C code; I wouldn’t like to speculate on using it via FFI.